# broken linux-generic or linux-headers-generic dependencies

Tags: dependencies

I can't install Ubuntu because of this.

[image: I try run command on which installer has stopped]

As I found there is no linux-headers-5.15.0-76-generic package in the repositories. What I can do to resolve this problem?

I'm using Ubuntu server 22.04 Jammy

Comment: Does your issue relate to https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-meta/+bug/2025192 ?

Comment: Yes this is same issue

Comment: I have the same one

Comment: I ran into this also. Refreshed my local mirror and it's OK now.

Answer (score 2):

Recently the problem was fixed.

update & upgrade :)

My ubuntu server was installed the updates correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Was receiving errors such as

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 linux-generic : Depends: linux-headers-generic (= 5.15.0.76.74) but 5.15.0.72.70 is installed
```

Fixed the issue by trying `$ sudo apt --fix-broken install`

It installed the required headers and performed sanity checks for various packages, and fixed the broken headers issue.