# linux-image-5.15.0-76-generic not installing due to missing packages on Ubuntu 22.04.2

Tags: apt, package-management, kernel, dependencies

> **root@ubuntu22:~# lsb_release -a 
>
> LSB Version:    core-11.1.0ubuntu4-noarch:security-11.1.0ubuntu4-noarch 
>
> Distributor ID: Ubuntu 
>
> Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS 
>
> Release:        22.04 
>
> Codename:       jammy**

> **root@ubuntu22:~# apt install linux-image-5.15.0-76-generic 
> Reading package lists... Done 
> Building dependency tree... Done 
> Reading state information... Done 
> Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have 
> requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable 
> distribution that some required packages have not yet been created 
> or been moved out of Incoming. 
> The following information may help to resolve the situation: 
> The following packages have unmet dependencies: 
> linux-image-5.15.0-76-generic : Depends: linux-modules-5.15.0-76-generic \but it is not installable 
> E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages. 
> root@ubuntu22:~# apt search linux-modules-5.15.0-76-generic 
> Sorting... Done 
> Full Text Search... Done 
> root@ubuntu22:~# \

> Looks like the dependency for linux-image-5.15.0-76-generic such as linux-modules-5.15.0-76-generic is not available through the jammy repository which prevents installation of linux-image-5.15.0-76-generic**

There is no such problem in the installation of linux-image-5.15.0-75-generic

Comment: Possibly related to https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-meta/+bug/2025192 and https://askubuntu.com/questions/1475121/broken-linux-generic-or-linux-headers-generic-dependencies/1475131 (on this site)

Comment: It is the same as reported in [link](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-meta/+bug/2025192)

Comment: Refreshed my local mirror, it works now.

Answer (score 2):

The package `linux-modules-5.15.0-76-generic` is now available for installation.

Ref: https://ubuntu.pkgs.org/22.04/ubuntu-updates-main-amd64/linux-modules-5.15.0-76-generic_5.15.0-76.83_amd64.deb.html

Comment: Nope. Not on 22.04