# broken linux-generic or linux-headers-generic dependencies REDUX

Tags: kernel, 22.04, dependencies

i concur with this same question asked here by others. on ubuntu 22.04.2. this was all preceded by 'apt-get update':

```
root@host3:~# apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  linux-image-virtual
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
root@host3:~#
```

followed by:

```
root@host3:~# apt-get install linux-image-virtual
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 linux-image-5.15.0-76-generic : Depends: linux-modules-5.15.0-76-generic but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
root@host3:~#
```

followed by:

```
root@host3:~# apt-get install linux-modules-5.15.0-76-generic
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Package linux-modules-5.15.0-76-generic is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'linux-modules-5.15.0-76-generic' has no installation candidate
root@host3:~#
```

Comment: I refreshed my local mirror and it's OK now.

Comment: does 'apt-get update' not accomplish that refresh? excuse my naivety if not...unless i just need to possibly try using different mirrors than my server currently has configured perhaps.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [broken linux-generic or linux-headers-generic dependencies](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1475121/broken-linux-generic-or-linux-headers-generic-dependencies)

Comment: no. in fact that topic is what mine is based on. i imagine it's what @OrganicMarble suggested, and my mirrors are simply not fully up to date yet with current available packages. i will just wait and try again later then. thanks everyone.

Comment: You can check mirrors using https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archivemirrors though if your selected mirror isn't *up-to-date*, switch to a different mirror (*even if only temporarily*)  FYI:  *The page I provided I believe is only refresh on cron job, so may not always be perfectly current, but temporarily using another mirror is a quick way to test I feel*

Comment: "does 'apt-get update' not accomplish that refresh? " I have my own mirror because I have so many devices. Doing *apt-get update* connects to whatever mirror your configuration specifies - in my case, it's the local one. When my mirror updated from the official ones at 2am here and I subsequently (hours later) tried to update a system, I got the same problem you are running into. After looking into it a bit, I forced my local mirror to refresh, and then the update worked. My conclusion was that the main mirror had some kind of problem, which they corrected.

Comment: i can confirm my mirrors have been refreshed and it now works OK. thanks.